# Division in a finite field, $1/2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is $3$

Tags: finite-fields

I was watching my math lecture for a course and we were doing inverse matrices in finite fields in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. The determinant was $1 / (6-4)$ so $1/2$ which apparently means it is 3. I have no idea where 3 comes from, is $1$ over $2$ the same as division or does that mean something else?

I am entirely new to fields and have very limited knowledge on them, but my searches never revealed anything about division or what this would be for the determinant.

Comment: could be modular math 3*2=6 6 has a remainder 1 when dividing by 5.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $2\cdot 3=6=5+1\equiv 1\pmod{5}$. This means that in the [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) $\mathbb{Z}_5$, the element $2$ is invertible  and the [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Uniqueness_of_identity_element_and_inverses) of $2$ (what you call $1/2$), is $3$.

Comment: Ah, right, so it's like a double inverse sort of thing. Since 1/2 would have an inverse of 2 and 2 would have an inverse of 3 and since if you take the inverse of something twice you would end up with the same something. Does this mean 1/3 in Z5 would be 2? If so you have answered my question

Comment: @Patrick Yes, you are correct $2^{-1}\equiv 3$ and $3^{-1}\equiv 2$ modulo $55.

Answer (score 2):

Division is *defined* the same way in modular arithmetic as it is on the regular number line. In other words, $\frac12$ is the unique number such that $2\cdot \frac12 = 1$. However, since modular arithmetic works differently from regular arithmetic, the *interpretation* of the above definition is very different: We have $2\cdot 3 = 1$, which means that $3$ actually fulfills the defining property of $\frac12$. We can also easily check that there are no other such numbers, so it is unique. That is why $\frac12 = 3$.

Note for later: If you ever have to solve quadratic equations in modular arithmetic (at least as long as it's modulo an odd prime), the formula $\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ still works, except once again, the *definition* of $\sqrt{{}\cdot{}}$ is the same (sortof; there isn't anything like positive / negative to distinguish the two square roots of a number), but the *interpretation* is different, with, for instance, $\sqrt{-1} = \pm 2$ modulo $5$.